# Can't restore a flink job that uses Table API and Kafka connector with savepoint

Tags: apache-flink

I canceled a flink job with a savepoint, then tried to restore the job with the savepoint (just using the same jar file) but it said it cannot map savepoint state. I was just using the same jar file so I think the execution plan should be the same? Why would it have a new operator id if I didn't change the code? I wonder if it's possible to restore from savepoint for a job using Kafka connector & Table API.

Related errors:

```
used by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint file:/root/flink-savepoints/savepoint-5f285c-c2749410db07. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator dd5fc1f28f42d777f818e2e8ea18c331 to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.

used by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint file:/root/flink-savepoints/savepoint-5f285c-c2749410db07. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator dd5fc1f28f42d777f818e2e8ea18c331 to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.
```

My Code:

```
public final class FlinkJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String JOB_NAME = "FlinkJob";

        final EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
        final TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
        tEnv.getConfig().set("pipeline.name", JOB_NAME);
        tEnv.getConfig().setLocalTimeZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ApiLog (" +
                "  `_timestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp' VIRTUAL," +
                "  `_partition` INT METADATA FROM 'partition' VIRTUAL," +
                "  `_offset` BIGINT METADATA FROM 'offset' VIRTUAL," +
                "  `Data` STRING," +
                "  `Action` STRING," +
                "  `ProduceDateTime` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(6)," +
                "  `OffSet` INT" +
                ") WITH (" +
                "  'connector' = 'kafka'," +
                "  'topic' = 'api.log'," +
                "  'properties.group.id' = 'flink'," +
                "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '<mykafkahost...>'," +
                "  'format' = 'json'," +
                "  'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'" +
                ")");

        tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE print_table (" +
                " `_timestamp` TIMESTAMP(3)," +
                " `_partition` INT," +
                " `_offset` BIGINT," +
                " `Data` STRING," +
                " `Action` STRING," +
                " `ProduceDateTime` TIMESTAMP(6)," +
                " `OffSet` INT" +
                ") WITH ('connector' = 'print')");

        tEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO print_table" +
                " SELECT * FROM ApiLog");

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a different Flink version when you tried to restore?

Comment: @MartijnVisser No. I'm using the same Flink version :(

Comment: If you are using the same Flink version and the same application code, this would be a bug. Could you create a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK/issues/ ?